# SSRS handle #Error when reportitems textbox = "N/A"

Tags: reporting-services, expression

SSRS handle #Error when reportitems textbox = "N/A"

When Textbox88 = N/A I am getting #Error in the % cell/column.

The N/A is from a iff(isnmeric(Lookup expression ending with: =FALSE,"N/A"

How can I modify below expression to handle "N/A" in another field?

Result can simply be another "N/A" in the percentage column.

Current expression not handling #Error..

`=(ReportItems!Textbox55.Value - ReportItems!Textbox88.Value) / ReportItems!Textbox88.Value`

Switch? 
IIF?

Answer (score 0):

The #Error is a compiler error that is usually caused by conflicting data types. In your above example, it would seem you are trying to use a string "N/A" in a math equation.

First, I recommend to everyone that you cast the data to what you want it to be, not what you expect it to be. You can do this using the CSTR() - string, CINT() - integer and CDEC() - decimal, functions.

For example:

```
=(CINT(ReportItems!Textbox55.Value) - CINT(ReportItems!Textbox88.Value)) / CINT(ReportItems!Textbox88.Value)
```

This may solve your problem by forcing the data type of the text box to be an integer. You may still get a #Error, however, because the function will return 0 for a string with no numbers and you will get a divide by zero error.

Therefore we can error check with an IIF:

```
=IIF(ReportItems!Textbox55.Value = "N/A" or ReportItems!Textbox88.Value = "N/A", "N/A", (CINT(ReportItems!Textbox55.Value) - CINT(ReportItems!Textbox88.Value)) / CINT(ReportItems!Textbox88.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

ended up using custom code: replaced the =FALSE, "N/A" with = FALSE, 0

Public Function Divide(ByVal dividend As Double, ByVal divisor As Double) As Double
   If IsNothing(divisor) Or divisor = 0 Or IsNothing(dividend) Or dividend = 0 Then
      Return 0
   Else
      Return dividend / divisor
   End If
End Function

expression:

= Code.Divide((ReportItems!Textbox55.Value - ReportItems!Textbox88.Value),ReportItems!Textbox88.Value)